# Windows 10 cannot find VPN Server, although it works on another PC

Tags: windows-10, vpn

**My Setup:**

I am using Windows 10 on a MacBook Pro from 2017. Windows is installed using the MacOS Boot Utility, so it's not a VM. I did successfully connect to the vpn in MacOS, but it did only work when using my phones mobile hotspot, my home wlan or ethernet did not work.

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to connect my PC to a VPN Server (L2TP/IPsec with pre-shared key). The secret, password, ip and username are correct, I've checked many times. I have a second pc in my home network, settings are exactly the same (not a MacBook, "normal" pc) and there the vpn works perfectly fine.

**The error message:**

The network connection between your computer and the VPN server could not be established because the remote server is not responding. This could be because one of the network devices (e.g, firewalls, NAT, routers, etc) between your computer and the remote server is not configured to allow VPN connections. Please contact your Administrator or your service provider to determine which device may be causing the problem.

**What I have tried:**

- restart my pc
- reinstall windows
- use ethernet / wifi / my mobile hotspot
- disable ipv6
- restart the router

I have no clue what to do because the setup is exactly the same on the other pc and there it works perfectly fine and fast.

**Edit:**
I am not sure what vpn it is, because it's owned by a friend, but as mentioned, it works fine from different pcs in the same network as well as from my android phone. Also I forgot to mention that I tried disabling all windows firewalls and that I don't have any anti virus software or anything similar installed.

Comment: try another vpn

Comment: Which VPN are you using? Have you looked into the firewalls in-between?